# Update manager updates the kernel mod but not the nvidia client, how to get them to match?

Tags: nvidia, kernel, update-manager, proprietary, jockey

12.04 update on 2012-12-22 updated the kernel to 3.2.0-35-generic and attempted to update nvidia driver to nvidia-experimental-310 310.14-0ubuntu0.1 but did not.

Update on 2013-01-06 update manager updated the kernel module to nvidia-experimental-310 310.14-0ubuntu0.1 but apparently did not update the actual driver, leaving it at 304.43.

So after the update, X fails due to kernel mod/graphics driver mismatch.  This leaves me with only a console.

This system is a straight up install with Ubuntu provided proprietary nvidia drivers.

What do I need to do from console to get the client & kernel version to match?

jockey.log is [here](http://pastebin.com/ufL8z97G), and here are other log extracts:

```
from dpkg.log
2012-12-22 10:15:29 configure linux-image-3.2.0-35-generic 3.2.0-35.55 <none>
2012-12-22 10:15:29 status unpacked linux-image-3.2.0-35-generic 3.2.0-35.55
2012-12-22 10:15:29 status half-configured linux-image-3.2.0-35-generic 3.2.0-35.55
2012-12-22 10:16:47 status installed linux-image-3.2.0-35-generic 3.2.0-35.55
skip
2012-12-22 10:54:19 install nvidia-experimental-310 <none> 310.14-0ubuntu0.1
2012-12-22 10:54:19 status half-installed nvidia-experimental-310 310.14-0ubuntu0.1
2012-12-22 10:54:27 status triggers-pending man-db 2.6.1-2
2012-12-22 10:54:27 status half-installed nvidia-experimental-310 310.14-0ubuntu0.1
2012-12-22 10:54:27 status triggers-pending desktop-file-utils 0.20-0ubuntu3propietary
2012-12-22 10:54:27 status half-installed nvidia-experimental-310 310.14-0ubuntu0.1
2012-12-22 10:54:27 status triggers-pending gnome-menus 3.4.0-0ubuntu1
2012-12-22 10:54:27 status half-installed nvidia-experimental-310 310.14-0ubuntu0.1
2012-12-22 10:54:32 status unpacked nvidia-experimental-310 310.14-0ubuntu0.1
2012-12-22 10:54:32 status unpacked nvidia-experimental-310 310.14-0ubuntu0.1
2012-12-22 10:54:32 install nvidia-settings-experimental-310 <none> 310.14-0ubuntu0.1
2012-12-22 10:54:32 status half-installed nvidia-settings-experimental-310 310.14-0ubuntu0.1
2012-12-22 10:54:32 status not-installed nvidia-settings-experimental-310 <none>
skip
2013-01-06 10:59:13 startup packages configure
2013-01-06 10:59:13 configure nvidia-experimental-310 310.14-0ubuntu0.1 <none>
2013-01-06 10:59:13 status unpacked nvidia-experimental-310 310.14-0ubuntu0.1
2013-01-06 10:59:13 status unpacked nvidia-experimental-310 310.14-0ubuntu0.1
2013-01-06 10:59:13 status half-configured nvidia-experimental-310 310.14-0ubuntu0.1
2013-01-06 11:00:51 status installed nvidia-experimental-310 310.14-0ubuntu0.1
from syslog
Jan  6 11:22:50 64bitwrksta kernel: [    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-35-generic root=UUID=98396955-e718-4c04-83fa-b23dbb537615 ro quiet splash
skip
Jan  6 11:22:53 64bitwrksta kernel: [   32.642878] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 304.43, but
Jan  6 11:22:53 64bitwrksta kernel: [   32.642880] NVRM: this kernel module has the version 310.14.  Please
Jan  6 11:22:53 64bitwrksta kernel: [   32.642880] NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
Jan  6 11:22:53 64bitwrksta kernel: [   32.642881] NVRM: components have the same version.
Jan  6 11:22:53 64bitwrksta kernel: [   32.643200] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 304.43, but
Jan  6 11:22:53 64bitwrksta kernel: [   32.643201] NVRM: this kernel module has the version 310.14.  Please
Jan  6 11:22:53 64bitwrksta kernel: [   32.643202] NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
Jan  6 11:22:53 64bitwrksta kernel: [   32.643203] NVRM: components have the same version.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from multiple installs of nvidia, the solution is to remove the unwanted ones.

This should be run from a console **without** X running.

Find out which ones are installed- `sudo dkpg --list | grep nvidia`

From the console: `sudo dpkg --list | grep nvidia` which will give you something like:

```
ii  nvidia-common                                 1:0.2.44.2                                         Find obsolete NVIDIA drivers
ii  nvidia-current                                295.40-0ubuntu1.1                                  NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library
ii  nvidia-current-updates                        304.43-0ubuntu0.1                                  NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library
ii  nvidia-experimental-310                       310.14-0ubuntu0.1                                  Experimental NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library
ii  nvidia-settings                               295.33-0ubuntu1                                    Tool of configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-settings-updates                       304.43-0ubuntu0.2                                  Tool of configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

presumably (undocumented) `ii` means installed and `rc` means removed.

Then you remove the unwanted ones, for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-experimental-310
```

The run: `sudo apt-get autoremove` which gets rid of unneeded dependencies, for me `nvidia-settings`

Then to put a lid on it, run for the desired driver (for me): `sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-current-updates`

Now my sudo dpkg --list | grep nvidia looks like:

```
ii  nvidia-common                                 1:0.2.44.2                                         Find obsolete NVIDIA drivers
rc  nvidia-current                                295.40-0ubuntu1.1                                  NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library
ii  nvidia-current-updates                        304.43-0ubuntu0.1                                  NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library
rc  nvidia-experimental-310                       310.14-0ubuntu0.1                                  Experimental NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library
rc  nvidia-settings                               295.33-0ubuntu1                                    Tool of configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-settings-updates                       304.43-0ubuntu0.2                                  Tool of configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

I reboot and I have X working again.